# Google Reports API for Meet attendance - strange conference_id

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-reporting-api

I'm trying to query attendance for a Google Meet conference created via Google Calendars API.
I've found that the conferenceId returned by Calendar API > Events > insert it's different from the one I can use to filter in Reports API.

1. conferenceId from Calendar API --> ["conferenceId"]=>string(12) "xxx-xxxx-xxx"
2. conferenceId from Reports API{"name": "conference_id", "value": "xxxxxxx_12234XXXXXxxxxXX56"}

Does anyone knows why?
How can I query attendance based on the data returned by Calendar API > Events > insert ?

Steps to reprocuduce:

1. Insert calendar events (be sure to add conferenceData structure to create also the Meet conference):
   https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert
2. Use the conference
3. List activities from Report API and check the conference_id: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I've updated the question with the steps to reproduce

Comment: do a calendar.get you will see the the conference type that will be inserted

Comment: It's a meet (Google meet) The problem it's that there's no uniformity between the conferende_id in Calndar API and the conference_id in Reports API

Comment: Why would there be its two different systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `conferenceId` from the Calendar event object is different from the `conference_id` in the Reports (note that the name is different). The [`activities.list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) output also has another field called `meeting_code`, it's also under `items.events.parameters`:

```
{
    "name": "meeting_code",
    "value": "ASDFASFFGJ"
}
```

This one matches the `conferenceId` in a calendar event, except that it's without dashes and capitalized, so for the example `"conferenceId": "asd-fasf-fgj"` in a Calendar [Event](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events#resource) object you'll find `"meeting_code": "ASDFASFFGJ"` in the activity reports. So you can just remove the dashes and capitalize the `conferenceId` to match it to its corresponding `meeting_code`.

As to why this discrepancy exists, my guess after reading the [definition of the Meet activity events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet) is that it tracks different "conference sessions" within the same meeting code. For example, if you join the meeting `asd-fasf-fgj` it will create a new `conference_id` until everyone leaves the meeting. Then if the same meeting code is used again a different `conference_id` will be created to track the new session and so on.

I did some cursory testing and the logs do create a different `conference_id` every time I joined the same Meeting code. I didn't have multiple accounts to test so I'm not sure if two users can have matching IDs, but I may be close. I couldn't find any in-depth documentation so it would require more testing to figure out exactly how it works.

Either way, to address your immediate concern, you should be able to match the Event's `conferenceId` with the Report's `meeting_code` to track the attendance.

##### Reference:

- [Meet Activity log definition](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/meet)